# Emptying an electrolytic separator in mekanism?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods, minecraft-mekanism

I'm trying to set up a 3x ore processing system in the FTB-Hermit-Pack.On the wiki, the electrolytic separator is said to have two differently colored tanks on each side, but the new textures for mekanism 1.10 take away the colors, so I am unsure if I'm even setting this up right. I can't get any oxygen to come out of the separator, even though the pipe visually connects. How do I get oxygen into the tube?

Here is a screenshot of the separator GUI:
[image: Image of GUI, Power is full, water is full, hydrogen is dumping, and oxygen is full and idle. The device is set to work regardless of redstone.]
As you can see, the separator has enough water and power, and enough oxygen (The yellow stuff) to fill the pipe. I'm sure I'm doing this right.

Now, I know that might not be enough to tell what's going wrong, so here's how everything is connected:
[image: Electrolytic Separator is facing toward the player. It is recieving power from an EnderIO conduit from the top, and is connected to a mekanism pressurized tube, which visually connects to the right side of the separator, but has no oxygen in it. (IIRC you can see the oxygen inside the tube)]
The separator doesn't have colored tanks, but regardless of which side I connect the pressurized tube to (I've tried every side), it doesn't actually give oxygen to the pipe, which is stopping my processing from working.

The pipe doesn't travel too far. Here's where it goes:
[image]
These are elite factories. The pipe connects to the top of an elite purifying factory. This factory should accept oxygen, but none is going in.

If it matters, I'm not loading the Electrolytic Separator with mekanism pipes; I'm loading it with an ExtraUtils2 Fluid Transfer Node. Here is the node:(directly behind the separator)
[image]
So, out of my entire setup, my issue is that I can't get the oxygen from the separator into the pipe. What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix my machine?

EDIT:
I am aware that there are alternative ways to get 3x ore processing (I have a smeltery in the background of the pictures, that does 3x ores in FTB HermitPack), but I want to get this done with a setup that works quickly and is easy to automate.

Comment: I can change the question to include a screenshot of my setup and ask hiw to fix. I just thought a savegame might be more helpful to others.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better. A savegame is a non-starter as an answer/solution because it can't be hosted on Arqade, and if someone linked to it, it would eventually disappear and make the solution not useful. So best to keep it to “here's my setup, how do I fix it?”

Comment: I've updated the question with screenshots :D

Comment: Cool! Vote retracted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is indeed with your pipe setup. To fix the issue, you have two options:

1) You can use an item called the configurator to set inputs and outputs on the gas pipes.

2) You can move the separator to be touching the elite factory, eliminating the need for a pipe.

Either of these should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks self! I used the configurator on each edge of the pipe, setting it to pull the oxygen and push it into the factory.